# Git command to push the files without cloning

Tags: git

I have a requirement,

1. I need to clone a remote branch to Local.
2. Add some files the local folder
3. Push the changes to some other existing  remote branch.

But, when I do got push, it is actually cloning the remote branch details in to my local, and then pushing it.
Because of that, I am losing the newly added files in my local (those will be overwrite) and those files will not push to the other branch.

The command I am using to push is as below:

```
git init  
cd git_test
git fetch
git checkout repobranchB
git add -A
git commit -m "test"
git push
```

Is there any option in git push, where it will not clone the existing files in the remote branch to local? I just need to add all the files in my local to the specified remote branch.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right. You are supposed to work from an existing remote branch that you will clone? Where is the clone operation (or you adding the remote in the new repo and fething from it)?

Comment: When you do `git init` it will initialize a new empty repo in your current directory. There are no branches nor remotes defined in your (new, empty) repo. So `git fetch` and `git checkout repobranchB` will both fail in your given example. To push a commit, you need to commit it locally before pushing. To add a child commit (i.e. a commit with another commit as parent) to a repo, you need to have the repo.

Comment: "I need to clone a remote branch to Local" But you never do that. It is step 1 so you need to do it first.

Comment: Git does not push files. Git only pushes *commits*. You must make a commit that contains the desired file snapshot, and push that. The way to do that is to use a Git repository. Since commits link to previous commits, you'll need a clone of the existing repository, so that your new commit can add on to the last existing commit of some branch.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to:

1. Checkout the branch
2. Pull remote changes (temporarily)
3. Make YOUR changes to the files
4. Commit and push to remote
5. Checkout your old branch again locally

You can even delete the local branch if you no longer need it:

```
git branch -d repobranchB
```

Commits on one branch should not effect another unless you 'git add...' the changes while on that branch. When you switch back to the original branch your changes won't be there

https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches